# Compile SASS on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, sass, compass-sass

Is there an app to compile SASS (maybe even compass) on the iPad? I don't want do some server-side stuff. I can do that but I want to do it even if I'm not connected.

Comment: You'd think that would violate Apple's "no programming" rule. SASS probably isn't turing complete, but you can still do math with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to code from your ipad.

Currently there's no way to do that locally on iOS; The closest thing to that would be using a Javascript port of sass (https://github.com/visionmedia/sass.js) to make a offline HTML5 app for copy paste compiling.

My advice is to run compass watch on the server that you're developing on via SSH